# How does starred expression works when using with find_element() method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

```
def enter_text_textbox(self, locator, text):
    ele = self.driver.find_element(*locator)
    try:
        logging.info("# Entering text in Textbox.")
        ele.clear()
        ele.send_keys(text)
        return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

Here is a method enter_text_textbox which accepts locator and some text as parameters.
I passed locator as something like this:
        self.email_field = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']")

When I tried to get into this(self.driver.find_element(*locator)) method, it displayed[image]

As from the image the methods contains parameters of ID only.

By running the test script(not displayed here), it worked perfectly fine.
I want to know how does this method know if this locator is made by XPATH or ID or CSS i.e. How the starred expression works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a really nice question which allowed me to think a lot and I was expecting someone (with more python experience) to answer this.

Coming to the answer, a couple of things to note here:

To locate an element, you can directly call the `find_element_by_*`, directly which internally calls `find_element` api. It is also suggested to use the explicit `find_element_by_*`.

If you look at the find_element api signature,

```
find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None)
```

the **default initialized value** for `by` is `By.ID`. So don't get confused with the `by` type you are sending and the default value. When you deep dive, you will see, if the by *type is ID, NAME, TAG_NAME, CLASS_NAME*, the by type is converted to `CSS_SELECTOR` and the value is also converted to its corresponding *css_selector_value*.
After that, 
If the by type is anything else apart from the mentioned above, it just executes that command.

```
elf.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
            'using': by,
            'value': value})['value']
```

The second part of the question, 'The starred argument':

Take a look at this for a better understanding of *args and **kwargs in python:

https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWY4BZi_o28

(basically arguments can be both 'packed' and 'unpacked' using the star and double star syntax)